# Is it possible to use alternative search engines with Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm currently evaluating the possibility to use Stack Overflow for Teams for my department. As an active user of Stack Overflow in past I think it's a great idea and Q&A format would probably work in most of teams setups.

**What I'm concerned about is**:

> Everyone knows that for IT-questions, Google is a frontend page for Stack Overflow that serves as a backend

.. because let's be honest, search is far from perfect on Stack Overflow. If I google the question, usually first 1..3 links land me to a correct answer on Stack Overflow. Often enough that's even the very first link.

Therefore I'd like to know if it will be possible to use different search engine for Stack Overflow Teams.

**Why I ask this**: we will evaluate the Stack Overflow Teams and if that goes well - good chances are we want to use it for all IT departments in different Business Units / Countries. that would be >2000 IT persons actively using it so the knowledge base will grow rapidly and we need good search.

Comment: Using alternate search engines for Stack Overflow-hosted Teams is likely to be challenging... But for the sort of eventual scale you're talking about, you'd probably want to go with self- or cloud-hosted Enterprise anyway. Do you have an existing solution for intranet search?

Comment: @Shog9 Yes.. Atlassian and Salesforce solutions. We know how "good" it is. That's why together with using something better for documentation / knowledge sharing, we want to improve search first and foremost. I get it, google is that good for search because it's their business - so I don't expect SO to integrate google into it (and that would not fit for enterprise anyways)

Comment: So... My guess is that the integrated site search is gonna be about as good as you can get for *just* searching Teams... But a real win here would be integration with other enterprise systems, to where you wouldn't need to know the info was on SO before searching. I'd be interested to hear what others are using for enterprise search these days; I know Google Search Appliance is going the way of the dodo, but I'd expect there are some hefty cloud based services now that wouldn't even break a sweat at indexing something like this along with other internal docs.

Comment: I agree that it could be an interesting research on what others are using and if that leads to some ideas - I hope there will be some improvements for SO Teams on this account

Comment: Google used to have indexing servers you could mount in your own racks to keep stuff private but still benefit from googles algorithms.. but that was ages ago. They had golden cases if I remember correctly.

Comment: The search engine in SO is not that bad. You mention Atlassian, Confuence has a search tools also but for me it's not better than SO (expecially when you have a huge amount of docs). For me it's not SO which should include a new search engine but existing search engine, at entreprise level (like Confluence), that should search in SO Teams.

Comment: I believe that a big part of Stack Overflow search engine failure is that **it doesn't index code**. So whenever you use the formatting syntaxes with backticks or with four spaces, searching for it becomes impossible. In practice, this often affects multi-line error messages as well. So it may not be because ElasticSearch is bad, but more about how it is configured.

Comment: @Cœur it does index code! We probably could improve how we use that field however.

Answer (score 8):

It likely won't ever be possible to use a different search engine for Stack Overflow for Teams, but I want to re-assure you that we have a renewed interest in improving our internal search. In fact, we launched an experiment last week and have another launching in the next few days. It's very important to us to improve our search so that Teams is as useful as possible to everybody. I won't make any concrete promises, but I'll tell you that we will be iterating (and testing) a ton on search over the next few weeks and months.

Comment: [UIToolbarPositionAny search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIToolbarPositionAny) not finding https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205345/.
[InternalUriParseQueryStringToDictionary search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=InternalUriParseQueryStringToDictionary) not finding https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341732/.
[constrainedInternetAccess search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=constrainedInternetAccess) not finding https://stackoverflow.com/a/15922631/.
["Hello int" search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Hello+int%22) not finding https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360759/

Comment: Please note that I am in China where Google is blocked, so I've been forced to use the Stack Overflow internal search for years, and in the end I often find myself going to https://data.stackexchange.com/ to perform simple searchs that Elastic Search current configuration can't handle.

Comment: @Cœur it's how we're doing the code block analysis. See [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=forToolbarPosition%3AUIToolbarPositionAny) by comparison

Comment: Thank you, it's interesting but that's not an obvious search query to prefix an enum value with a method name. In comparison, if I go on Apple documentation website and I simply [query for UIToolbarPositionAny](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=UIToolbarPositionAny) I get perfectly fine results. No need to be in context.

Comment: Right. I think we'll run an experiment to analyze the code with an English tokenizer (separate words by things like `.` and `:` etc.) - I bet that'll be quite successful!

Comment: To be clear: I fully agree that current code search is too rigid; we will fix it.

Comment: Ok, from my learning: first, there is no possibility to use custom search engines in SO Teams and it is not planned; second - there is some work in progress for it. Thus for us it would mean - when this work is done, we could try it, but for now it won't solve our problems, so we won't evaluate it further currently. Thanks for honest answer!

Comment: @AlmaDo for a larger org, consider Enterprise: https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise

Comment: @Haney, another small searching issue is that looking for [reachability permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reachability+permissions) gives 1,925 results, but if you make a light mistake like [reachbility permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reachbility+permissions), then it yields 0 results at all. The [same light mistake on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=reachbility+permissions+site%3Astackoverflow.com) will give 704 results. I know that this issue is harder to fix.

Comment: Could you all please talk about **this** in your blog more than you do about "welcoming" issues? This is the kind of stuff we *want* to hear about!